# Azure SQL Server automatic tuning - Drop index

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

If I allow Azure to automatically drop indexes, will they only drop indexes that they auto-created or even on ones that I created?

Answer (score 0):

REF: [Automatic tuning for SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automatic-tuning-overview)
It will drop both indexes Drops (unused over the last 90 days) and duplicate indexes with some exceptions.

- Unique indexes, including indexes supporting primary key and unique constraints, are never dropped.
- This option may be automatically disabled when queries with index hints are present in the workload, or when the workload performs partition switching.
- On Premium and Business Critical service tiers, this option will never drop unused indexes but will drop duplicate indexes, if any.
- It automatically validates there exists a positive gain to the workload performance, and if there is no significant performance improvement detected, it will automatically revert the tuning recommendation.

My recommendation: If you are not you can disable auto-deployment but still receive recommendations. Do due diligence and apply manually.